# ZK error selecting date

Tags: java, zk

I have some problem with converting datebox format on ZKoss. The log output is as follows:

```
input?
Fri Jan 04 00:00:00 UTC 2002choosing date
test1
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Jan"
  Position: 49
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2096)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1829)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:510)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271)
    at controller.jurnal.jurnalDAO.getLKeuangan(jurnalDAO.java:46)

//error ommited
```

**This is my controller class**

```
public class JournalController extends GenericForwardComposer {

    private Listbox listlk;
    private Datebox datebox;
    private koneksi k;
    private Connection c;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    private Button pilih;

    public JournalController() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);

    }

    public void onClick$pilih() throws Exception, SQLException {
        try {
            getListlk();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getListlk() {
        try {

            Date dates = datebox.getValue();

            System.out.println("input?");
            System.out.println(dates + "choosing date");

            koneksi k = new koneksi();

            jurnalDAO jd = new jurnalDAO(k.getConnection(), dates);
            List<Jurnal_tbl> ltsu = jd.getLKeuangan();
            listlk.setModel(new ListModelList(ltsu, true));

            listlk.setItemRenderer(new ListitemRenderer() {

                public void render(Listitem lstm, Object o) throws Exception {
                    Jurnal_tbl jt = (Jurnal_tbl) o;
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
                    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String tanggal = sdf.format(jt.getTanggal());

                    new Listcell(jt.getKode()).setParent(lstm);
                    new Listcell(jt.getTransaksi()).setParent(lstm);
                    new Listcell(tanggal);
                    new Listcell(jt.getAkun()).setParent(lstm);
                    new Listcell(jt.getDeskripsi()).setParent(lstm);
                    new Listcell(jt.getDC()).setParent(lstm);
                    new Listcell(Double.toString(jt.getAmount())).setParent(lstm);
                    new Listcell(jt.getItem()).setParent(lstm);

                    //     System.out.println("test keluar" + tanggal + jt);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            k.closeConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

**My DataAccessObject Class:**

```
public class jurnalDAO {

    private Connection conn;
    private Date tanggal;

    //    private String pilihbulan;
//    private String pilihtahun;
//    JournalController lkc = new JournalController();
    public jurnalDAO(Connection conn, Date dates) {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.tanggal = dates;
    }

    public List<Jurnal_tbl> getLKeuangan() throws SQLException, Exception {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        //      JournalController lkc = new JournalController();

        try {
            List<Jurnal_tbl> llk = new ArrayList<Jurnal_tbl>();
            System.out.println("test1");
            String sql = "select * from public.jurnal where tanggal = " + tanggal;
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                llk.add(new Jurnal_tbl(rs.getString("kode"), rs.getString("transaksi"), rs.getDate("tanggal"), rs.getString("akun"), rs.getString("Desc"), rs.getString("dc"), rs.getDouble("amt"), rs.getString("item")));
            }

            rs.close();
            return llk;
        } finally{
        }
    }
}
```

**And my finally my zul's page:**

```
<window title="Untitled Journal" width="auto" height="auto" border="" apply="controller.jurnal.JournalController">

                        <grid>
                            <rows>
                                <row>
                                    <hlayout>
                                        <div>
                                            <datebox id="datebox" cols="16"  format="yyyy-MM-dd"  mold="rounded"/>
                                            <button id="pilih" label="pilih"/>
                                            <button id="cetak" label="Cetak" image="images/Print.png"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </hlayout>
                                </row>
                            </rows>
                        </grid>
                        <listbox id="Listlk" >
                            <listhead>
                                <listheader label="Kode Jurnal"/>
                                <listheader label="No Transaksi"/>
                                <listheader label="Tanggal"/>
                                <listheader label="Account Number"/>
                                <listheader label="Deskripsi"/>
                                <listheader label="Debit/Credit"/>
                                <listheader label="Amount"/>
                                <listheader label="Item No"/>
                            </listhead>
                        </listbox>
                    </window>
```

I cant convert date format when datebox.getValue() returns jan 04 2002.
I wish the formatting to be (yyyy-MM-dd).

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Could you provide your table schema and how you save it ?
I bet it's the issue for your data saving , not for your data loading.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a ZK problem.
This code is your problem:

```
String sql = "select * from public.jurnal where tanggal = " + tang gal;
```

You make a transformation of java.util.Date#toString() which gives you default date presentation of a date you had.

Instead you have to put a parameter in your sql statement and then set it's value:

```
String sql = "select * from public.jurnal where tanggal = :myDate"
preparedCall = conn.prepareCall(sql);
preparedCall.setDate(":myDate", tanggal);
ResultSet rs = preparedCall.executeQuery();
```